# How to put array into Hashmap for encoding a JSON object

Tags: java, arrays, json, serialization, hashmap

I'm trying to send API call using json-simple 1.1.1 and I save fields and values as a HashMap. I should send those parameters:

```
{ api_key : string,
  product_id : string,
  name : string,
  tax_rates : array }
```

Here is a HashMap example:

```
HashMap<String,Object> arg = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            arg.put("product_id","42");
            arg.put("name", "EKOS");
            arg.put("tax_rates", taxarray);
```

I saved taxarray as a HashMap as well:

```
HashMap<String, Object> taxarray = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            taxarray.put("name","EKOS");
            taxarray.put("type", "type_value_fixed");
            taxarray.put("value", "56");
```

But when I execute an API call it reurns an error:   Parameter 'tax_rates' is not valid. The required type of parameter is an array.

I had been trying to save taxarray HashMap as JSONArray as well. Could you please help me with this?

An additional question: how can I save 2 or more taxrates within one "tax_rates"? Here is an example:

```
 HashMap<String,Object> arg = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                arg.put("product_id","42");
                arg.put("name", "EKOS");
                arg.put("tax_rates", array [
                                     taxarray1[],
                                     taxarray2[]
                                           ]);
```

Comment: As a suggestion you should use Json object to store the object eg:{
  "product_id": 42,
  "name": "EKOS",
  "tax_rates": {
    "a": "b",
    "c": "d",
    "e": "f"
  }
}

Comment: Hm... I would not recommend this approach.  `HashMap` is not an equivalent to a JavaScript object; its intent is to capture objects that implement the same interface.  While you CAN get this to work, it is not the Java way.  I would recommend trying something like the approach at https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/ to use existing tools to map your JSON to Java classes that capture your expected structure in a more Java way.

Answer (score 1):

You should have something like this - Tax class:

```
public class Tax {
    String name;
    String type;
    Integer[] values;

    public Tax(String name, String type, Integer[] values) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.values = values;
    }   
}
```

And then use an array of objects of Tax class instead of HashMap for `tax_rates : array`.

This code using google json:

```
Map<String, Object> arg = new HashMap<String, Object>();
arg.put("product_id", "42");
arg.put("name", "EKOS");
arg.put("tax_rates",
                new Tax[] { new Tax("EKOS", "type_value_fixed", new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 }),
                        new Tax("ABC", "type_value_fixed", new Integer[] { 4, 5 }),
                        new Tax("DEF", "type_value_fixed", new Integer[] { 6, 7}) });

Gson gson = new Gson();

System.out.println(gson.toJson(arg));
```

Will give you such json:

```
{
  "product_id": "42",
  "name": "EKOS",
  "tax_rates": [
    {
      "name": "EKOS",
      "type": "type_value_fixed",
      "values": [
        1,
        2,
        3
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "ABC",
      "type": "type_value_fixed",
      "values": [
        4,
        5
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "DEF",
      "type": "type_value_fixed",
      "values": [
        6,
        7
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I recommend this idea; it would be better even for the architecture of his project.

Answer (score 0):

`tax_rates` has to be an array, so do this:

```
List<Double> taxRates = new ArrayList<Double>();
taxRates.add(19);
taxRates.add(17.5);

Map<String,Object> arg = new HashMap<String, Object>();
arg.put("product_id","42");
arg.put("name", "EKOS");
arg.put("tax_rates", taxRates);
```